# Flutter WebView loadRequest

Tags: flutter, webview

i have this code of a webView Page and i wanted to create a code in which i enter something in the input of the appBar and when i click the search icon it redirects to that url but for some reason the loadRequest Method doesn't work and it shows no error this is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

import '../components/bottom_navbar.dart';

class WebViewContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();
  get controller => WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
    ..setNavigationDelegate(
      NavigationDelegate(
        onProgress: (int progress) {
          // Update loading bar.
        },
        onPageStarted: (String url) {},
        onPageFinished: (String url) {},
        onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
        onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
      ),
    )
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://www.google.com'));

  onSearch() {
    // Get the text from the search input.
    String url = _searchController.text;

    // Check if the URL has a scheme, and if not, prepend "https://".
    if (!url.startsWith('http://') && !url.startsWith('https://')) {
      url = 'https://' + url;
    }
    WebViewController().loadRequest(Uri.parse(url));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF0f3443),
          actions: [
            PopupMenuButton(
              itemBuilder: (context) {
                return [
                  const PopupMenuItem(child: Text("Settings")),
                  const PopupMenuItem(child: Text("profile")),
                  const PopupMenuItem(child: Text('Log Out')),
                ];
              },
            )
          ],
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          // The search area here
          title: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 40,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
            child: Center(
              child: TextField(
                controller: _searchController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                      onPressed: onSearch,
                    ),
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                      onPressed: () {
                        /* Clear the search field */
                      },
                    ),
                    hintText: 'Search...',
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 13.5)),
              ),
            ),
          )),
      body: WebViewWidget(controller: controller),
      bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavigationBarExample(),
    );
  }
}
```

i was expecting that my webview takes me to google if i type google i the search input for example

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new WebViewController every time you're trying to access or modify the WebView. You need to have a reference to the same WebViewController instance that's attached to your WebView widget.

Modify your `onSearch` to use `WebViewController instance`

```
void _onSearch() {
  String url = _searchController.text;
  
  if (!url.startsWith('http://') && !url.startsWith('https://')) {
    url = 'https://' + url;
  }
  
  controller.loadRequest(Uri.parse(url));
}
```

Comment: you provided me with a code that is old and it doesn't work on the new webView package

Comment: I updated the answer, the key point is that try to use one instance of `WebViewController`

Comment: nope it said WebViewer has no instance method loadUrl

Comment: `controller.loadRequest(Uri.parse(url));`